# Calculating IMU random walk using allan variance

Tags: ros, robotics, calibration, imu

I am trying to calculate accel and gyro noise and random walk for Intel realsense using [allan variance](https://github.com/ori-drs/allan_variance_ros). I quickly generated imu csv in the format specified [here](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr/wiki/bag-format) using custom CPP script for just 3 seconds. I wanted to check if it will work or not before recording 20 hours of IMU data.

I created ros bag from csv by running:

```
rosrun kalibr kalibr_bagcreater --folder ./data/imu_data --output-bag ./data/newbag.bag
```

Checking the bag created:

```
root@e9408da6622e:/data# rosbag info /data/data/newbag.bag  
path:        /data/data/newbag.bag 
version:     2.0 
duration:    2.4s 
start:       Dec 30 2023 18:41:25.42 (1703961685.42) 
end:         Dec 30 2023 18:41:27.84 (1703961687.84) 
size:        312.7 KB 
messages:    830 
compression: none [1/1 chunks] 
types:       sensor_msgs/Imu [6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2] 
topics:      /imu0   830 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu
```

Then I converted it to allan variance compliant bag by running:

```
rosrun allan_variance_ros cookbag.py --input /data/data/imu_data/newbag.bag --output /data/data/imu_data/cooked_bag.bag
```

Checking the bag created:

```
root@e9408da6622e:/catkin_ws# rosbag info /data/data/imu_data/cooked_bag.bag  
path:         /data/data/imu_data/cooked_bag.bag 
version:      2.0 
duration:     2.4s 
start:        Dec 30 2023 18:41:25.42 (1703961685.42) 
end:          Dec 30 2023 18:41:27.84 (1703961687.84) 
size:         41.7 KB 
messages:     830 
compression:  lz4 [1/1 chunks; 8.47%] 
uncompressed: 296.1 KB @ 122.5 KB/s 
compressed:    25.1 KB @  10.4 KB/s (8.47%) 
types:        sensor_msgs/Imu [6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2] 
topics:       /imu0   830 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu
```

I created allan variance config file imu_confog.yaml:

```
imu_topic: "/imu0"
imu_rate: 346
measure_rate: 346 # since bag contains 830 messages / 2.4 seconds = 345.8333 approx 346
sequence_time: 3 # since bag contains 2.4 seconds worth of data
```

(I also tried with both rates 400, no luck.)

Here is how my data folder looks like:

[image]

Then I run allan variance:

```
root@e9408da6622e:/catkin_ws# rosrun allan_variance_ros allan_variance /data/data/imu_data /data/data/allan_variance/imu_config.yaml
```

And finally run Analyse.py:

```
root@e9408da6622e:/catkin_ws# rosrun allan_variance_ros analysis.py --data /data/data/imu_data/allan_variance.csv --config /data/data/allan_variance/imu_config.yaml
/catkin_ws/src/allan_variance_ros/scripts/analysis.py:23: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  logy = np.log(y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/catkin_ws/src/allan_variance_ros/scripts/analysis.py", line 101, in <module>
    accel_wn_intercept_x, xfit_wn = get_intercept(period[0:white_noise_break_point], acceleration[0:white_noise_break_point,0], -0.5, 1.0)
  File "/catkin_ws/src/allan_variance_ros/scripts/analysis.py", line 24, in get_intercept
    coeffs, _ = curve_fit(line_func, logx, logy, bounds=([m, -np.inf], [m + 0.001, np.inf]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 708, in curve_fit
    ydata = np.asarray_chkfinite(ydata, float)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 495, in asarray_chkfinite
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

But as you can see it is giving error `array must not contain infs or NaNs`. Turns out there are some NaNs in allan_variance.csv file generated. What I am doing wrong here?

I have uploaded all bags and csv file on drive [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15M2P3NHtgvJvRPZMNqd5uMvz1R0GN-0S?usp=sharing).